# A continuous capture of a window sceen as QPixmap? for OpenCV

Tags: c++, qt6

I'm trying to get a live view of a specific window using `Qt6.6`. So far I have succeed to do that for the whole screen. However, when I implemented the code for a specific window I get stuck at capturing the window screen as QPixmap. The object is [QWindowCapture](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwindowcapture-members.html) but it doesn't have a method for capturing or something similar. Once I get that, I'll convert it into OpenCV format for further processing which is what I have done with screen capturing.  That's my goal why I need capturing.

Here is the code if you want to try it:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QScreen>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QImage>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QCapturableWindow>
#include <QWindowCapture>

QT_USE_NAMESPACE

class WindowListModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit WindowListModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;

    QCapturableWindow window(const QModelIndex &index) const;

public Q_SLOTS:
    void populate();

private:
    QList<QCapturableWindow> windowList;
};

class Screenshot {
public:
    void displayLiveView();

private:
    QPixmap grabScreen();
};

QPixmap Screenshot::grabScreen() {
    QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
    if (!screen)
        return QPixmap();

    return screen->grabWindow(0);
}

void Screenshot::displayLiveView() {
    while (true) {
        QPixmap pixmap = grabScreen();
        if (pixmap.isNull()) {
            qDebug() << "Failed to capture the screen.";
            continue;
        }
        QImage image = pixmap.toImage();
        cv::Mat mat(image.height(), image.width(), CV_8UC4, (void*)image.constBits(), image.bytesPerLine());
        cv::imshow("Live View", mat);
        
        // Break if 'ESC' is pressed
        if (cv::waitKey(30) == 27) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void captureAndShowWindow(const QString& windowName) {
    // Obtain a list of available windows
    WindowListModel windowListModel;
    windowListModel.populate();

    QCapturableWindow targetWindow; // Window we are looking for

    bool windowFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < windowListModel.rowCount(); i++) {
        QModelIndex index = windowListModel.index(i);
        if (index.isValid()) {
            QString currentWindowDesc = windowListModel.data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
            if (currentWindowDesc.contains(windowName)) {
                targetWindow = windowListModel.window(index);
                windowFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!windowFound) {
        qDebug() << "Window not found!";
        return;
    }

    // Capture the specific window
    QWindowCapture windowCapture;
    windowCapture.setWindow(targetWindow);
    //STUCK
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Print available windows
    WindowListModel model;
    for (int i = 0; i < model.rowCount(); i++) {
        QModelIndex index = model.index(i);
        if (index.isValid()) {
            QString windowDesc = model.data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
            std::cout << i + 1 << ". " << windowDesc.toStdString() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    Screenshot screenshot;
    screenshot.displayLiveView();
    captureAndShowWindow("Settings");

    return 0;
}
```

The CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(ScreenshotApp)

# Set up the required version of Qt 
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

include_directories(include)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/user/Qt/6.6.0/gcc_64/lib/cmake")

find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Widgets Multimedia REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV 4.7.0 REQUIRED)

set_property(SOURCE main.cpp PROPERTY SKIP_AUTOMOC ON)

add_executable(main main.cpp ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(main Qt6::Widgets ${OpenCV_LIBS} Qt6::Multimedia)
```

Now I'm working on Ubuntu but later the code should run on Windows.

Comment: There has to be QVideoSink if you want to handle the captured video (of window) on frame-by-frame basis.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Can you please give me more information about how can I implement that, just few notes?

Comment: If you do not understand Qt docs then perhaps try Qt own examples as illustration to docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtmultimedia-screencapture-example.html If you still don't understand then ask in context of that documentation and that example. What you assumed you can do tried to change and did not work. Otherwise it is rather confused to understand .. you made window, set it to capture object and are stuck.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Qt doesn't use OpenCV and I've already checked that example. I can set the window to capture object but I don't know how to use its data so I can use it with OpenCV!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to get `targetWindowId` and feed that to `QScreen grabWindow`. This will give you `QPixmap` format which is easily converted into `OpenCV` `cv::Mat`.

For that I picked a class which is called private in Qt source code because it is not part of their API.

```
class QCapturableWindowPrivate : public QSharedData {
public:
    using Id = size_t;

    QString description;
    Id id = 0;

    static const QCapturableWindowPrivate *handle(const QCapturableWindow &window)
    {
        return window.d.get();
    }

    QCapturableWindow create() { return QCapturableWindow(this); }
};

class Screenshot {
public:
    Screenshot(const QString& windowName);
    void displayLiveView();

private:
    QPixmap grabWindow();
    WId targetWindowId = 0;
    QWindowCapture windowCapture;
};

Screenshot::Screenshot(const QString& windowName) {
    WindowListModel windowListModel;
    windowListModel.populate();

    QCapturableWindow targetWindow; // Window we are looking for

    bool windowFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < windowListModel.rowCount(); i++) {
        QModelIndex index = windowListModel.index(i);
        if (index.isValid()) {
            QString currentWindowDesc = windowListModel.data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
            if (currentWindowDesc.contains(windowName)) {
                targetWindow = windowListModel.window(index);
                windowFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!windowFound) {
        qDebug() << "Window not found!";
        return;
    }

    windowCapture.setWindow(targetWindow);

    auto handle = QCapturableWindowPrivate::handle(targetWindow);
    targetWindowId = handle ? handle->id : 0;
}

QPixmap Screenshot::grabWindow() {
    if (targetWindowId == 0) return QPixmap();

    QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
    if (!screen) return QPixmap();

    return screen->grabWindow(targetWindowId);
}

void Screenshot::displayLiveView() {
    while (true) {
        QPixmap pixmap = grabWindow();
        if (pixmap.isNull()) {
            qDebug() << "Failed to capture the window.";
            continue;
        }

        QImage image = pixmap.toImage();
        cv::Mat mat(image.height(), image.width(), CV_8UC4, (void*)image.constBits(), image.bytesPerLine());
        cv::imshow("Live View", mat);

        if (cv::waitKey(30) == 27) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Print available windows
    WindowListModel model;
    for (int i = 0; i < model.rowCount(); i++) {
        QModelIndex index = model.index(i);
        if (index.isValid()) {
            QString windowDesc = model.data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
            std::cout << i + 1 << ". " << windowDesc.toStdString() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    Screenshot screenshot("Settings");
    screenshot.displayLiveView();

    return 0;
}
```